# User profiles and command line arguments in MS Edge?

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

I am writing an application which is at one point expected to launch an Edge window. I'd like this new instance of Edge to be completely separate from other Edge windows in the system (so that it doesn't inherit cookies, favourites and other things). In other words, I am looking for a behavior similar to Chrome's **--user-data-dir** flag. Is this possible with Edge? I've looked around and it seems that the only command line parameter accepted by Edge is **:url**, and changing the user profile directory is rather cumbersome and involves fiddling with the registry, which is not an option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS are planning to release a Chromium-based Edge in the future and have already begun the migration. Currently (as of 12 October, 2019) there is a beta (78.0.276.17) version available, where the following parameter is working fine:

```
msedge.exe --user-data-dir="C:\ChromeBrowser_profiles\Profile_edge"
```

Note that executables are available at:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Beta\Application`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Beta\Application\78.0.276.17`

When loading a profile from another Chromium browser the apps don't open but a file CrashpadMetrics-active.pma is created in the profile directory.

Comment: Good one, apparently Edge is going to be Chromium-based from now on, which resolves this problem. Sadly when the issue first came up I had to deal with a version from early 2017. I believe it makes sense to accept this with an edit.

Comment: thanks for the edit  and its corrections.BTW the information provided above applies to Edge beta for windows7. Seem logical that same parameters shoudl apply to Edge for windows10 but I cannot confirm it.

Answer (score 3):

With chromium based Microsoft edge you can use...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge_proxy.exe"  --profile-directory=Default www.google.com

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge_proxy.exe"  --profile-directory="Profile 1" www.google.com
```